# Connecting Kube cluster through proxy and clusterIP?

Tags: kubernetes

As various google articles(Example : [this blog](https://www.ovh.com/blog/getting-external-traffic-into-kubernetes-clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer-and-ingress/)) states that this(connecting Kube cluster through proxy and clusterIP) method isn’t suitable for a production environment, but it’s useful for development.

My question is why it is not suitable for production ? Why connecting through nodeport service is better than proxy and clusterIP  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets distinguish between three scenarios where connecting to the cluster is required

1. **Connecting to Kubernetes API Server**
   Connecting to the API server is required for administrative purposes. The users of your application have no business with it. 
   The following options are available

   - Connect directly to Master IP via HTTPS
   - [Kubectl Proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/http-proxy-access-api/) Use `kubectl proxy` to to make the Kubernetes API available on your localhost.
2. **Connecting external traffic to your applications running in the Kubernetes Cluster**. Here you want to expose your applications to your users. You'll need to configure a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) and they can be of the following types

   - **NodePort**: Only accessible on the NodeIPs and ports > 30000
   - **ClusterIP**: Internal Only. External traffic cannot hit a service of type ClusterIP directly. Requires ingress resource & ingress controller to receive external traffic.
   - **LoadBalancer**: Allows you receive external traffic to one and only one service

**Ingress**: This isn't a type of service, it is another type of Kubernetes resource. By configuring [NGINX Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) for example, you can handle traffic to multiple ClusterIP services with only on external LoadBalancer.

3. **A Developer needs to troubleshoot a pod/service:** `kubectl port-forward`: [Port forwarding example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) Requires `kubectl` to be configured on the system hence it cannot be used for all users of the application

As you can see from the above explanation, the proxy and port-forwarding option aren't viable options for connecting external traffic to the applications running because it requires your `kubectl` installed and configured with a valid `kubeconfig` which grants access into your cluster.

Comment: Does kube proxy play any role in nodeport service ? I mean when connecting external traffic to application in kube cluster through nodeport service where kube-proxy comes into picture ?

Comment: Kube-proxy is a cluster component responsible for implementing services on the nodes. It sets up the forwarding rules for Node Port, Cluster IP or LoadBalancer.